# GoogleApiClient duplicate country value in Database

Tags: android, google-api-client

If I select the same location on a smartphone in GoogleApiClient  with English language and other phone with Romanian/Russian(other language) I had a problem because the country is the same but it is wrote different, what can I do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can localize your activity in English  and GoogleApiClient  will work in this activity only in  English

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
String languageToLoad  = "en"; // your language
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
setContentView(R.layout.activity_search); //initialize google api
```